# Передача данных с плохим интернетом

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как, и с помощью каких средств написать хорошую функцию для передачи текстовых данных через интернет. Главный критерий, чтобы можно было легко отловить разрыв связи и продолжить отправку с прежнего места, т.к. интернет у одного из устройств крайне нестабилен.

Comment: Обратите внимание на технику `message queuing`. В комментарии не опишешь всего, поэтому на досуге погуглите. Может быть то, что как раз нужно. Программа получается довольно простая и не надо самостоятельно заботится о повторе передачи. Всё делает очередь. Правда доставка сообщений будет асинхронная и конечно понадобится установка и настройка `message queuing middleware`.

Comment: Про Message Queuing читал уже давно, вещь хорошая, но мне она не подходит по ряду причин, самая основная это то, что разрыв связи может быть очень длительным( сутки и более), а данные записываться в очередь будут каждую секунду. Если останавливать запись в очередь и при подключении продолжать работать с ней, то, как мне кажется, лучше уж напрямую и отсылать эти данные на сервер.

Comment: Вообще-то не надо останавливать запись в очередь. Сообщения принимаются в очередь, хранятся хоть вечно в зависимости от настройки. Как только связь с сервером будет установлена, всё будет передано. Если на другой стороне тоже установить message queuing middleware и наладить мост (или роутинг. не знаю как точно называется) между ними, то и чтение из очереди не надо останавливать.

Comment: А message queuing middleware настраивается/устанавливается средствами c# или же встроенное в ОС что-то?

Comment: Встроенное в ОС или дополнительное ПО. В виндовсе есть встроенное MSMQ. Настройка как с помощью стандартной консоли, так и с помощью API

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую. А проблем с передачей не возникает, подводных камней много?

Comment: Я бы первым делом обратил внимание как связать между собой два сервера MSMQ, чтобы действительно самостоятельно не заниматься проблемами повторной передачи. А отправка и приём мессаг из программы никаких трудностей не вызывает. C# нормально сопрягается с MSMQ.

Comment: Вот меня в первую очередь и интересует связь между двумя компьютерами, надежно ли работает, как с потерями данных дело обстоит и что-то в этом роде... Спасибо за советы, начну изучать!

Answer (score -1):

Я бы передавал с помощью HTTP post запроса.

```
private async Task<string> SendData()
        {            
            var uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content", "Menya zovut Maxim"),
             });

            var client = new HttpClient();
            // Header'ы, если нужны
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", GlobalToken.token);
            // Отправка запроса
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), formContent);
            // Получение ответа
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic jsonResult = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
            return jsonResult.token; 
        }
```

Далее имеется 2 варианта:

1) Парси ответ, если в нём есть ответ о успешном получении.

2) Если сервер не отвечает о успешном получении - используй конструкцию try-catch.

Comment: С post запросами дел не имел, сейчас почитаю про них, поэтому пример пока мне не понятен.

Comment: Почитал я про post и get запросы.Они отправляют данные на url ссылку сайта получается? Либо я что-то не понимаю, либо мне она не подходит, т.к. концепция моего приложения клиент-серверное приложение и подключение клиентской к сервер будет реализовано через ip адрес. Или я всё же ошибаюсь?

Comment: Да, отправляются через url.
Значит тебе не подойдёт решение.